# Plugin Development - Functions or Hooks?

Tags: plugins, functions, hooks, actions, customization

I am brand new to WordPress plugin development and have a few questions, mostly about best practices but also some specifics.

Essentially I just want to trigger an action (invoking a PHP class and calling a method) whenever the following happens:

- A post is published
- A page is published
- A comment is added

This will be site-wide, so no need to key in anything specific just yet.  I know in the past people had used the add_action() function but that is now deprecated so any insight on best practices and how to accomplish the above would be much appreciated.  To get started I am using: https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate just to ensure I have proper structure, etc.

Comment: [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) is most definitely **not** deprecated and your best bet to accomplish what you need.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I must have read something wrong then, glad to hear it isn't deprecated.  Any input on writing a simple plugin that can hook into those three actions I mention in the post?

Comment: Ahh and see notes here as to why the deprecation was confusing, I must have linked to one of the other resources: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I've included two hooks you *could* use. There may be better hooks depending on what you're trying to accomplish exactly but this is what you've asked for. At the bottom I've listed some helpful resources:

**Publish Post Hook**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post

```
function published_post( $ID, $post ) {
    if( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        ...
    }

    if( $post->post_type == 'page' ) {
        ...
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'published_post', 10, 2 );
```

**Comment Post Hook**

```
function maybe_published_comment( $ID, $approval_bool ) {
    ...
}
add_action( 'comment_post', maybe_published_comment, 10, 2 );
```

**Resources**

1. [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)
2. [Developer Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/)

   1. [WP_Publish_Post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_publish_post/)
   2. [Comment Post Hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_post/)